# docker-compose ignores .env file when using `COMPOSE_FILE`

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I keep all my docker stuff in a `docker/` subdir under my project root, including `docker-compose.yml` and `.env`.

When I run:

```
$ docker-compose -f /path/to/my-project/docker/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

everything works fine. However, I'd like to avoid having to specify `-f` every time, so I set the `COMPOSE_FILE` variable:

```
$ export COMPOSE_FILE="/path/to/my-project/docker/docker-compose.yml"
$ docker-compose up -d
WARN[0000] The "DJANGO_DB_USER" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "DJANGO_DB_NAME" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "DJANGO_DB_PASSWORD" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "DJANGO_DB_PASSWORD" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
...
```

Unfortunately, the `docker/.env` file is no longer used when using `COMPOSE_FILE` as opposed to specifying via command line.

What's the best practice for handling this? My main goal is to not have to type a long command every time I want to run a compose command.

I'm using `docker-compose` version 2.2.3

Comment: I suppose you don't want to run the command inside of `docker/`?
According to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file) it seems that you would have to use `--project-directory`.

Comment: I'd like to be able to use the command regardless of my working directory. Specifying `--project-directory` every time defeats the purpose of using the environment variable in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `-f` flag to point to the compose file, the `.env` needs to be *next to the compose file*. However, if you use the variable `COMPOSE_FILE` then the `.env` needs to be at `PWD`, so *where you invoke the compose CLI*.

That is why I tend to put my .env file at the root of my project and add variables as such:

```sh
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=my-project
COMPOSE_FILE=.docker/compose.yaml
```

The project name variable is useful so that compose doesnt name the project just `docker`. If have this pattern in a couple different project, you end up with name clashes when not setting the project name.

This allows me to hide all the docker related cruft in its own directory and still being able to just do `docker compose up`.

The only thing is that you need this env file or another mechanism such as direnv/.envrc to let compose know what you want to do.

Comment: Will I be able to execute compose commands from other subdirectories? That is, will docker-compose see the env file in the parent dir, or do I always have to execute commands from the same dir?

Comment: @BenDavis, probably not and even if, the path would be probably messed up because its relative. You would probably need to set an absolute path. I suggest looking into `direnv` which can export these variables for you and looks also in parents https://direnv.net/

Comment: I personally rarely cd around my project. Most if not all things I need to do can be done from the root. So, I never really thought about this, but it's an interesting question.